# close dropdown of qcombobox

Tags: c++, qt, dropdown, qcombobox

I have a problem with the `QComboBox`. When I click on it, it opens the dropdown-menu. Good so far. Then (after some time) I add a screensaver Image `QFrame` in front of all UI (so also in front of the `QComboBox`) but the dropdown-menu is still visible (above the 'QFrame' of my screensaver image).

*First* I tried to programmatically click on some other object to perform the closing of the dropdown-menu. The other object was clicked, but the dropdown-menu was not going to close:

```
void GUI::click(QObject *obj)
{
    QMouseEvent evtPress(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, QPoint(0, 0), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
    qApp->sendEvent(obj, &evtPress);
    QMouseEvent evtRelease(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, QPoint(0, 0), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
    qApp->sendEvent(obj, &evtRelease);
}
```

The *second* approuch I thought of, is, to list all `QComboBoxes` and to close the dropdown-menu in a `for` or `foreach` loop. But the application is rather big and I don't really want to do that for two reasons:

- Manually collect all `QComboBoxes` and closing menus: does not support further modifications.
- Programmatically collect all `QComboBoxes` and closing menus: is rather slow I think (and I don't know how to do it eather).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling and reenabling de combobox. If the dropdown is open and then the combobox is disabled, the dropdown will close.

```
ui->comboBox->setEnabled(false);
ui->comboBox->setEnabled(true);
```

You can get every child that is a combobox in your UI using the [findChildren](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) method and use a for loop to close them:

```
QList<QComboBox*> children = ui->centralWidget->findChildren<QComboBox*>();
```

Here is a little example using a timer to close it after 2 seconds:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QTimer>
#include <QList>
#include <QComboBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Test");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Test2");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Test3");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Test4");
    ui->comboBox_2->addItem("Test5");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setText("The dropdown is open!");
    ui->comboBox->showPopup();
    ui->comboBox_2->showPopup();

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this, timer]{

        //THIS    
        QList<QComboBox*> children = ui->centralWidget->findChildren<QComboBox*>();

        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            children[i]->setEnabled(false);
            children[i]->setEnabled(true);
        }

        ui->label->setText("The dropdown has been closed!");
        timer->stop();
    });
    timer->start(2000); //time specified in ms*/
}
```

[image: dropdown example]

Comment: so how do I get all `QComboBoxes` out of my UI programmatically? Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem. As you said in your question, a way of doing this is storing them in a list and use for loop closing them as I've shown. It won't really hurt performance, it is a really small operation, even reapeating it multiple times. You can also create a method that enables/disables every combobox of your UI one by one, without a for loop (like I've done in my simple example).

Comment: Your answer is good. But I need a list of `ui` `qcomboboxes` and this list would be rather big. I mean **big**. Shure, if I have no other choice, I would do it with a manually created list, but I am frightened to do so.

Comment: @Michael1248 check my updated answer to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: That solution is so much better. Thank you very much.